# Why particles not seen in render

Tags: particles

Why i cant see particles or group of particles created. I created simple shape and added particles to it. And created group to that shape. To the mesh i have created particles and the above group i have assign. In the 3d view i see the mesh but no particles and in when i render i cant see particles (i have hide the mesh just to see the particles). What is missing why i cant see the particles in 3d view and in render view.

[Download this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xi4z368Sr6DXy6eNz5BUG500jnzazAIy/view?usp=sharing)

**Simple mesh created added particles created group**

[image]

**With the above group created assign to the mesh. Which is view in 3d view but no particles seen on it.**

[image]

**In render no particles seen which are assign. No Mesh No particles in final render**

[image]

Any suggestion or help why particles not seen in render and 3d view. Thanks

Comment: Hope the object group is not hidden from rendering?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the start and end frames of the particles, and the frame you are rendering.

Also check the Object Particle Size

Also check the particles render option to see if Emiter is set to Render

Comment: I look all the setting is perfect/ As the file is to heavy so cant send. Can u plz try. Take 3 mesh different type add particle setting on it and hide the emitter make a group of them. Take a land mesh and add this group.Let see what result you get. Thanks

Comment: I've gotten your point.

Comment: download this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xi4z368Sr6DXy6eNz5BUG500jnzazAIy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You are trying to use particle object in another particle object. I've also tried such while creating a fireworks effect... It ends up same as yours... Not rendering... You need to look for alternative to accomplish the task... You can convert the 1st particle in the "Modifier Tab" before using it in another "Particles"

Comment: But in that way the file size will be much heavy.

Comment: Yes... But if it worth it... You just have to do it... If you want to do that, you can save the file as new file